# Unable to install cucumber eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

I am trying to install Cucumber Eclipse Plugin from Eclipse marketplace. It is giving an error message at the end stating the following : 'Installing Software' has encountered a problem . Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found .

Answer (score 1):

HOW TO INSTALL CUCUMBER ECLIPSE PLUGIN

- Open Eclipse
- Help > Install New Software > Add
- Name: Cucumber
- Location: https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site
- Then hit Add button
- You will see Cucumber Eclipse Plugin. Check the box
- Hit Finish button
- Then hit Install Anyway
- Then hit Restart.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem with Eclipse. You should try installing the Eclipse PDE Plug-in Developer Resources before attempting to install Cucumber Eclipse. You can get it from the Eclipse p2 repository for your IDE version (for instance http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.12/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### ***Quick answer***

*Go to Help →* ***Install new software → Here uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”***

*Please check and let's know if it solved your problem.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple plugins for gherkin/cucumber available. You didn't provided which plugin you are trying to install and which is your eclipse version. There can be one of 3 possible reasons:

1. Not all the plugins supports eclipse latest versions.
2. You didn't selected Contact all update sites option
3. You are inside VPN and not able to access specific url.

For #1 you can check supported eclipse versions for the plugin at marketplace plugins details page under additional details. Try installing one which is supported on your eclipse version. For example, on [qaf-bdd-editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/qaf-bdd-editors) plugin details you will find it supports all versions including latest as of today (*Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Oxygen (4.7), Photon (4.8), 2018-09 (4.9), 2018-12 (4.10), 2019-03 (4.11)*).

For #2 you should try selecting Contact all update sites option

For #3 you need to download/get plugin zip and install from local